# Noun clause coming out of nowhere

Tags: relative-pronouns, clauses

Is the bold text correct, grammatically?

> Labor Party candidate Shannon Burch has promised to walk 300 kilometers in an effort to beat sitting congresswoman Susan Wells in next year's election. Wells, from the National Party, has been in office for 15 years and is fairly popular. Burch, meanwhile, is not well-known, **something she hopes to change by meeting as many of the state's 1.5 million citizens as possible during her walk.** In current polls, Burch trails Wells by 35 percentage points.

I think the thick part is just a noun clause that suddenly came out of nowhere.
There is no verb or something that takes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not uncommon: the noun phrase headed by *something* stands in apposition to the main clause; it is in effect a supplementary predication. The sense is *[that Burch is not well-known is] something she hopes to change...*

Comment: Thank you for the answer very much, but I don't get it even after I repeatedly read your answer. Could you add more explanation for me?

Comment: @SmartHumanism In the same way a noun phrase can be set in [*apposition*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition) to another noun phrase to describe it more fully--for instance *My son [the rock drummer]*, where the appositive phrase is in brackets-- a noun phrase can also be set in apposition to an entire clause: *He can play very fast, [a skill he practices for hours]* .

Comment: Thank you further for the added answer. Your explanation are so intelligent. These are so helpful to me and I've understood it totally. Thank you again and have a lovely day.